# Modify Aggregation Panel view

Tags: aggregation, edit-mode-panel

how can I modify aggregation panel items? I need to hide Title of current calendar (see picture below). 
I've got Sharepoint Online 2013. I try it in Sharepoint Designer. But I don't want to hide all Aggregation Panel, only item "Dovolenkovy kalendar" , which is title of viewed Calendar.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide that with the help of CSS as an approach.
Before that you need to read this [article](http://davidlozzi.com/2012/01/26/color-code-your-sharepoint-calendar/), In that David has explained how the CSS class is being referred by each of the overlay calendar.

From that I have found that if you place below CSS snippet as a script editor web part on that page or you can place it in your own CSS file.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-acal-apanel-color { display: none; }
</style>
```

> *Make sure this CSS snippet only appears where you want to hide the main calendar item as shown in your snap.*

In my example there were two calendars:

[image: My List of Calendar]

As I have inspected on HTML DOM elements found the following:

[image]

In above snap you can see in both `li` elements different class is provided: `ms-acal-apanel-color` (default calendar color) and `ms-acal-apanel-color4` (other overlay calendar color).

I have just applied CSS to hide the first element of that calendar items.

Comment: Hi Pradip, that's great! It really works! Thank you so much!

Comment: and how can I hide mini calendar in the left corner of window? Can I use the same script with other ID? What's the name of this calendar?

Comment: There should be div with ID `DatePickerDiv`. You can use that id and specify the css with `display: none` property.

Comment: I've add Script Editor with this: <style type="text/css">
    .ms-DatePickerDiv { display: none; }
</style>    but nothing happend. I see this mini calendar. Any idea?

Comment: Try this: `<style type="text/css"> #DatePickerDiv { display: none; } </style>`

Comment: again nothing. everthing is visible :(

Comment: Better you inspect that calendar DOM element with the help of developer tools and check which ID or class is being referred for that mini calendar and then specify this CSS with respect to the ID or class.

Comment: This is code what I see with help of developer tools: <div id="DatePickerDiv" style="display: block;">    When I use this ID in your JavaScript, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

The following jQuery example demonstrates how to hide a specific calendar panel:

```
function hideCalPanel(name)
{
    var calPanel = $('.ms-acal-apanel-item:contains("' +  name + '")');
    calPanel.parent().hide();
}

hideCalPanel('My Calendar');    //put the proper name of panel here, e.g. Dovolenkovy kalendar
```

**How to apply the changes**

1. Open the calendar page in `Edit` mode
2. Add `Content Editor` or `Script Editor` web part on the page
3. Insert the specified JavaScript code by enclosing it using
   `script` tag into web part
4. Save the changes

Comment: I've use your JavaScript with proper name of panel, bud now I've got one more web part and I always see "Dovolenkovy kalendar". What am I doing  wrong way? Please, see pictures below. Thanks